# why tex4ht do not change font size of \verb? when including \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, tex4ht, make4ht

This MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}
  \ifdefined\HCode
  \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \else
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
\else%assume pdflatex, I only use these two 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi 

\begin{document}        
\ifluatex
  compiled with lualatex
\else
  compiled with pdflatex
\fi 

{\tiny \verb|IllustratingTheUseOfDiscreteDistributions|}

{\tiny IllustratingTheUseOfDiscreteDistributions}    
\end{document}
```

When compiled with pdflatex or lualatex gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but when compiled with tex4ht either in lua mode or not, gives this HTML

```
 make4ht t.tex
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can one tell tex4ht to change the font size of `\verb` just like with pdflatex?

Using TL 2016

---

Update. Found the problem.  It is this `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` when it is included then make4ht do not change the font size of `\verb`. This now works

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}
  \ifdefined\HCode
    \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
\else%assume pdflatex, I only use these two 
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi 

\begin{document}        
\ifluatex
  compiled with lualatex
\else
  compiled with pdflatex
\fi 

{\tiny \verb|IllustratingTheUseOfDiscreteDistributions|}

{\tiny IllustratingTheUseOfDiscreteDistributions}    
\end{document}
```

Now `make4ht t.tex` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: why do you always use `\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}`  but not, for example `\IfFileExists{ifluatex.sty}{\usepackage{ifluatex}}{}` ? It doesn't matter, just looks a bit odd.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle because `luatex85.sty` only exist in TL 2016 and not TL2015. Since I still sometimes compile on TL 2015 to test, I needed this so not to get errors. `ifluatex.sty` package is in TL2015 and TL2016 since not need to check for it. `MWE>kpsewhich ifluatex.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
MWE>kpsewhich luatex85.sty
MWE>
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like an error in how `tex4ht` detects font sizes and converts them to css declarations. It is done by `tex4ht` command, so I don't really know and don't understand how it works, but the following test seems interesting:

```
{\ttfamily\tiny IllustratingTheUseOfDiscreteDistributions \itshape ojoj}            

{\ttfamily\footnotesize IllustratingTheUseOfDiscreteDistributions \itshape ojoj}

{\ttfamily\small IllustratingTheUseOfDiscreteDistributions \itshape ojoj}                     

{\ttfamily IllustratingTheUseOfDiscreteDistributions \itshape ojoj}

{\ttfamily\large IllustratingTheUseOfDiscreteDistributions \itshape ojoj}

{\ttfamily\Large IllustratingTheUseOfDiscreteDistributions \itshape ojoj}
```

With your original base font size (11pt):

[image]

With 10pt base font size:

[image]

And with 12pt:

[image]

As you can see, on each picture, there is at least one font size, which is converted incorrectly, but only at 11pt base font size there is an error with `\tiny` font size. This is certainly a bug.

As a fix, I would use custom CSS, after inspecting the HTML file, I found that monospaced tiny is converted as `<span class="ectt-0800x-x-75">` so I would just use something like:

```
\Css{.ectt-0800x-x-75{font-size:65\%;}}
```

in the .cfg file