# tex4ht changes \_ in math mode to X in HTML when not including \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} why?

Tags: tex4ht, font-encodings, make4ht

I had to comment out `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` when running tex4ht to bypass an issue [why-tex4ht-do-not-change-font-size-of-verb-when-including-usepackaget1font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318232/) but now I find a strange side effect for not inlcuding this package, which is tex4ht changes `\_` in math mode to `X` in the HTML !

This is auto-generated by Maple. So I am forced now to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Is there a reason why tex4ht changes `\_` to `X` when not including `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

PDF has no problem, it is only tex4ht. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\ifdefined\HCode
  \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
   %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %do not use. Make tex4ht \verb not accept  different fonts
\else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi   

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}    
\[ 
    y = \_C1
\]    
\end{document}
```

Compiled using  `make4ht --lua -u foo.tex` and this is the output

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While `lualatex foo.tex` gives PDF

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Question is: Must one include `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for tex4ht to give correct outpout? only reason I do not include is to due to the font issue size I linked to above, else I would just include it. And is this is what tex4ht should do? Why it works ok with pdf?

ps. At first I thought it was the `\it` which causes this, but now I see it is the `\_` so I edited the question slightly.

Comment: For reasons I don't know (but probably for denoting some HTML entity), when `\_` is processed in your test file, eventually `\a:HChar` is used, which expands to `x`. This has nothing to do with `\it`; try with `\[\_y={\it \_C1}\]` and you'll get an x in front of y as well; curiously, not with `$\_y={\it \_C1}$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is clearly this definition from `latex.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{textundescore}[1]{\expandafter
\def\csname ?\string\textunderscore\endcsname{\leavevmode#1}}
\Configure{textundescore}{\HChar{95}}
```

`\HChar` includes special instruction for tex4ht DVI processor to replace next character (which is `x`) with character with value `95`. As math is converted to image by other DVI processor (`DVIPS` or `DVIPNG`), which doesn't understand this instruction, the character which should be removed, `x`, remains here instead of `_`. we need to disable the use of `\HChar` in mathmode, use `\mathunderscore` instead.

Unfortunately, LaTeX default definition of `\_` inserts `\textunderscore` even in math mode:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\_}{%
\ifmmode\nfss@text{\textunderscore}\else\textunderscore\fi}
```

we can change it to use `\mathunderscore` in the math mode:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\_}{%
  \ifmmode\mathunderscore\else\textunderscore\fi}
```

You can try it with the following `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\_}{%
  \ifmmode\mathunderscore\else\textunderscore\fi}
\EndPreamble
```

The result:

[image]